# upload multiple file via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code to upload multiple file. Input file generated dynamically so i am calling this FileUploader function where these input file generated. But I have to click twice to upload file. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
FileUploader: function($dis) {
                    var fileName = '';
                    var $htm = $($dis.parents('div.sfFormInput').find('div.cssClassUploadFiles'));
                    var $ht = $($dis.parent('div.uploader'));
                    var extension = new RegExp($ht.attr('extension'), "i");

                    var upload = new AjaxUpload($('#' + $dis.attr('id') + ''), {
                        action: Path + "UploadHandler.ashx",
                        name: "myfile[]",
                        multiple: true,
                        data: {},
                        autoSubmit: true,
                        responseType: "json",
                        onChange: function(file, ext) {
                        },
                        onSubmit: function(file, ext) {
                            if ($ht.attr('almul') == "false" && $('div.cssClassUploadFiles').children('div').length > 0) {
                                csscody.alert('<h1>Alert Message</h1><p>You can upload only one file at  a time!</p>');
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (ext != "exe" && extension != '') {enter code here
                                if (ext && extension.test(ext)) {
                                    this.setData({
                                        'MaxFileSize': $ht.attr('filesize')
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    csscody.alert('<h1>Alert Message</h1><p>Not a valid file!</p>');
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        onComplete: function(file, response) {
                            var html = '';
                            var filePath = Path + "/UploadedFiles + file;
                            if (file.split('.')[1] == "jpg" || file.split('.')[1] == "JPEG" || file.split('.')[1] == "gif" || file.split('.')[1] == "bmp" || file.split('.')[1] == "png")
                                html = '<div title="' + Path + "UploadedFiles + file + '" ><img height="10%" width="10%" src="' + filePath + '"/><a class="sfDeleteFile"><img src="../Modules/FormBuilder/images/closelabel.png" /></a></div>';
                            else
                                html = '<div title="' + Path + "UploadedFiles + file + '" >' + file + '  <a class="sfDeleteFile"><img src="../Modules/FormBuilder/images/closelabel.png" /></a></div>';
                            $htm.append(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Code works but only issue is I have to click twice to upload file.

Comment: twice on what button on the file browser or the upload button that opens the file browser ?

Comment: @shareef Upload Button.At runtime input file generate.I think there is some problem or ????

Comment: How are you using your `FileUploader`? Are you binding any `click` event to the upload button? Include that code as well.

Comment: no I am not binding any click event to the upload button.

Comment: When are you triggering your upload function then? on form submit event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the fileuploading part, rather looks like in the initialization part. If your file upload control is dynamically created make sure you initialize the uploader after binding that in your markup.